# How to pre-compute the receipt_id/is the receipt_id pre-computed based on the transaction/transaction hash?

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I'm trying to link some receipts to the transactions it came from. I don't see a way from the docs to query a receipt and get the transaction it's associated with (there is only an RPC endpoint for transaction->receipt https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/transactions#transaction-status-with-receipts)

I also saw this [code blob](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/808d9343db79919911f87b332b0fbea0926b7f49/chain/indexer/src/streamer/mod.rs#L107-L116) from `nearcore` which seems to imply that I could do this without an RPC call by pre-computing it from a transaction.

EDIT: I found out how from digging through `nearcore`.

The hash is created with [this function](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/bf1c0738139ed665d5f00d211c305954dd0c73a7/core/primitives/src/utils.rs#L303) which is called by a [create_receipt_id_from_transaction function](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/bf1c0738139ed665d5f00d211c305954dd0c73a7/core/primitives/src/utils.rs#L207).